# Angular 2: Component doesn't render

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using a custom **component** in angular 2 but it **doesn't render**. I cannot find out why it doesn't render.

**Attempt 1:** This is the html page where the component is used (**doesn't work**):

```
<div class="container-fluid container-content" *ngIf="project">
    <div class="projectdetail" style="background: green">
        <img [src]="project.img" [alt]="project.name" style="height: 150px" />
        <h2>{{project.name}}</h2>
        <div>
            <carousel interval="5000" noWrap="false">
            <slide *ngFor="let slidez of slides; let index=index">
                    <img [src]="slidez.image" class="carouselimg" />
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h4>Slide {{slidez.id}}</h4>
                        <p>{{slidez.text}}</p>
                    </div>
                </slide>
            </carousel>
        </div>
        <p>{{project.description}}</p>
    </div>
    <!--hidden-mm hidden-sm hidden-xs-->
    <div class="projects" style="background: red">
        qsdfqsdfqsdf
        <projectlist></projectlist>
    </div>     
</div>
```

Screenshot(Nothing)
[image: Attempt 1]

**Attempt 2:** When I put the projectlist tag inside the div, then it **actually work**. Weird?

```
<div class="container-fluid container-content" *ngIf="project">
    <div class="projectdetail" style="background: green">
        <img [src]="project.img" [alt]="project.name" style="height: 150px" />
        <h2>{{project.name}}</h2>
        <div>
            <carousel interval="5000" noWrap="false">
            <slide *ngFor="let slidez of slides; let index=index">
                    <img [src]="slidez.image" class="carouselimg" />
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h4>Slide {{slidez.id}}</h4>
                        <p>{{slidez.text}}</p>
                    </div>
                </slide>
            </carousel>
        </div>
        <p>{{project.description}}</p>
<!-- ADDED THIS-->
        <projectlist></projectlist>
    </div>
    <!--hidden-mm hidden-sm hidden-xs-->
    <div class="projects" style="background: red">
        qsdfqsdfqsdf
        <projectlist></projectlist>
    </div>     
</div>
```

Screenshot (**Shows only one time (the second projectlist and not the first)**)
[image: Attempt 2]

I use the component somewhere else and there it actually works correctly, so don't know what the problem is.

Here is a github link: [Github](https://github.com/Ghosttje/Portfolio-TestProject)

**If you need extra info or code just ask.**

Comment: Did you check the browser console for errors?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Yea and there are no errors :)

Comment: if you don't see the custom component it means you forgot to tell angular about this component. check that you have a defined directive(rc4) or declaration (rc5) for this component.

Comment: it is just weird why it shows when I put it in the above div, and it actually shows only one time

Comment: When you add `console.log('xxx')` to the constructor of the component, does it get printed to the console in both cases?

Comment: I added some screenshots, and will test your console log now :)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer So the console.log actually print the correct count for both: with attempt 1: 1 print. And attempt 2: 2 prints.

Comment: Sounds like a CSS issue. Did you check the DOM if it is created?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer My dom says the following in the element: <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": null
}-->

Comment: If the constructor is called I'm pretty sure there will be the `<projectlist></projectlist>` tag as well. The `<!-- template ..>` comment is just a placeholder for `*ngFor`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer yea it looks ok but for some weird reason it looks like it doesn't load the data from the service!

Comment: Can't tell anything about that from the information you provided.

Comment: Can you paste your @Component code to ?

Comment: Create a plunker with your code. Use this boilerplate from Angular2 http://plnkr.co/edit/A2ht5m04o6vh7gaoNcmm?p=preview . I'm sure that someone will solve the problem in 1 minute after you create the example.

Comment: @tibbus I will do that as fast as possible :)

Comment: @tibbus I cannot get moment.js to work on plunker? it is needed to use with ng2-bootstrap: http://plnkr.co/edit/zJkn9u?p=preview

Comment: @tibbus I added a github link with the example :)

Comment: It's a chrome bug. http://take.ms/mfn9V

Comment: @yurzui ok, and is there an easy way to fix this because my mainstream browser is chrome :P

Comment: As workaround you can open `projectlist.component.ts` file and change `ngOnInit` method to `setTimeout(() => this.getProjects(), 0)`

Comment: @yurzui it looks to be the solution. Plz post as an answer so I can give you credit :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I investigated a bit this issue and found that the problem occurs only in chrome browser.

Chrome sends a request from `ProjectListComponent` with strange headers
[image]

As workaround you can solve it by the trick

**projectlist.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
  setTimeout(() => this.getProjects(), 0);
}
```